# Implementing methods: search, load and print

Tags: java

Please see my comments in the code to better explain things.  Basically having issues with the methods below.  I can get the load method to run but I am unsure whether the numbers entered by the user are actually being stored in the array.

In addition, the search method has been throwing things off and i think its going in a loop.

See below for more.  Thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyContainer {
private int[] values;
private int size;
public MyContainer(){
values=new int[50];
size=0;}

//Load Method - Display a message to the user 
//and get positive intergers from user
public void load()
{
int input;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a series of positive integers (Negative to Terminate): ");

input=in.nextInt();
while (input >=0) {
  values[size]=input;
  size++;
  input=in.nextInt();
}

}//End Load

//Compute Average from the above entered numbers
public double computeAverage() {
double avg= 0.0;
int count = 0;
while(values[size] >=0)
{avg = avg + values[size];
count++;
}
size = size + 1;
avg = avg / size;
return avg;

}

//Get user input to search for a number in the array
public boolean search(int myInt){

while(values[size] >=0) {
if (values[size] == myInt){
  return true;}
else{
  size++;}
}
return false;
}

 //print the position of the number
  public void print(){
   for(int i=0;i>=size;i++) {
   System.out.println("The number at position " + i + " is " + values[i]);
 }
 }
}
```

That is what I have so far.  I also have created a tester class for the above container.

```
   class Tester {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   MyContainer in = new MyContainer();
   in.load();
   in.computeAverage();
   in.search(); //i know for a fact this is wrong just stuck        
   in.print();    
 }
}
```

Any advise/help would be greatly appreciated.  My professor is terrible at teaching and the book only partially explains things.

Comment: Your `search` method has a parameter in the declaration, but you don't pass anything in your class `Tester`. Is this correct?

Comment: @DanielPereira - yes, I believe im also running an infinite a loop.  any help would help still confused with this program.

Answer (score 0):

Your search() method has parameters that you aren't passing.

you declare it as...

```
public boolean search(int myInt) {

    while (values[size] >= 0) {
        if (values[size] == myInt) {
            return true;
        } else {
            size++;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but call it with...

```
in.search();
```

This code won't even compile.  For argument sake I set this to 5.

In your `computeAverage()` method, this is an infinite loop...

```
while (values[size] >= 0) {
        avg = avg + values[size];
        count++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I believe you are running into is the reuse of your `size` variable. In the load function it will work as expected say for loading in 10 numbers `size` will be 10 and elements 0->9 in `values` will have numbers in them. However when you get to `computeAverage` size will still be 10. So you are in an infinite loop.

```
 while(values[size] >= 0) {
    avg = avg + values[size];
    count++;
 }
```

First iteration you will check `values[10]` (which is wrong  remember valid elements are only in 0->9 if `size` is 10). Next iteration `avg` and `count` are increased but `size` remains the same so you will add the same number to `avg` and continue in the loop. You should use a different conditional for your while loops in `computeAverage` and `search`. The last negative number entered to quit will not be in the array; you will need to use something else. As a hint it will involve `count` and `size`.